# Restore database from production to Development

Tags: postgresql

We have the database named 'itreport' on production server and database named 'itreport_dev' on development server.

1)On Production server, 52 users are present in the database 'itreport'.
2)On Development server, 60 users are in present the database 'itreport_dev'.
3)I have taken the dump of production server database 'itreport'. Dump file name is backup_12082017.sql

My question is 
 If I restore the above dump(backup) file to Development server database 'itreport_dev, Users(60) present will present in the Development database?

If not what option we have to give in the restore process?

What are the pre steps and post steps to be performed on Develpement server?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No, roles are not part of a single-database backup.

If you dump only the database using `pg_dump` it will only restore tables and data. not any roles. any objects owned by missing roles will end up owned by the user performing the restore (this user should be a superuser)

If you do `pg_dumpall` roles and all databases will be backed up.

Roles can be backed up separately using `pg_dumpall -r`

if you do `pgdumpall --clean` the resore will destroy and replace any databases and roles on the dev server that also exist in the dump.  any names that are not in both will be unaffected, (the special role "postgres" and template databases also are untouched)

pgdumpall backups are SQL backups and should be restores using psql

```
su postgres -c psql < all-database-backupfile.sql
```

or

```
zcat all-database-backupfile.sql.gz | su postgres -c psql
```

etc.

(for windows use runas instead of su, I'm not sure of the exact syntax needed)

Comment: Thanks Jasen, I have tested in environment. Whatever you said is correct. I dont know how to mark this correct answer. As of now voted